# Django-REST or Firebase?

Tags: django, reactjs, firebase, web, django-rest-framework

We are about to begin working on a project that was started by someone else. It is currently developed in HTML+CSS+Javascript and Firebase.

We'll move the frontend to React, but we are used to develop the backend on Django-REST deployed on AWS and have never really worked with Firebase (and honestly, don't really know how it works in detail).

React seems to have a nice integration with Firebase, but we would need to learn how it works.

Is it worth it to move the backend from Firebase to Django-REST? Which are the pros and cons of both of them?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Advantages of firebase-**

• Why firebase is created when pre established framework like Django is there..to reduce the complexity of framework..hence it's simpler to learn or more preferably it's a light weight.

• Real time data base management like you are indulged with app like for banking or other relies upon frequently change in users data then it is made for u.

• it facilitates​ you with the cloud messaging i.e you can send notification to users at a time with no cost.

• imparts authentication for Google,Twitter & Facebook & other.

• crash reports solution i.e if your one of the app crashes in any mobile you will be informed.

• doesn't need to separately integrate admob.its built in available in it

**Disadvantages of Firebase-**

• every perks come up with some cost..so firebase is not suitable for large projects as you will have to code lots of line.

• Not free you need to pay 25$ in a month,moreover it's cumulative with users i.e more user more load on pocket.

• Therefore it's not good for long term with so many users.

• your user data is somewhere in servers which you don't own,therefore it becomes hard to fetch all data & you will need to contact them.

**Advantages of Django-**

• Built with Python.which is easy to learn & faster,it is best structured webframe.

• it comes with its own ORM(object relationship mapping) i.e you connect your objects directly to relational database by writing code in Python.

• It has rich,pre established community..therefore you can instantly get answer of your queries.

•It provides you admin panel by which you can change,modify your database entries.

I suggest you to go with Django,it's kind of one time solution forever most suited for large application. At first it seems complex but once you will step into this things will be simpler for you.

But if u don't wanna get into complex framework & only want some real time small application with limited user.then you can switch to firebase.

Hope it helped u!

Comment: My Personal opinion is Django because provided wide range of functionality.